# Override variables in docker-compose env_file with the actual environment from the outside

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, env-file

Given a very simple [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    env_file:
      - my.env
    command: env
```

And the `my.env` file referenced in there:

```
FOO=BAR
```

Running `docker-compose up` prints as expected (container name prefix defaults to the name of the parent directory):

```
test_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
test_1  | HOSTNAME=00dc4fa7f38a
test_1  | FOO=BAR
test_1  | HOME=/root
tmp_test_1 exited with code 0
```

Overriding the variable from the `env_file` from the outside, as in `FOO=SOMETHING_ELSE docker-compose up`, will not be reflected in the container though. The output will still contain `FOO=BAR` as defined in the `my.env`.

Is it possible somehow to override variables defined in the `env_file` from the outside, without changing them inside the file? I know that it will work if I extend my `docker-compose.yml` file with the line

```
environment:
  - FOO
```

However, this does not really scale to a larger amount of variables - one always has to make sure that the `env_file` and `docker-compose.yml` are in sync to prevent nasty bugs.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a way to do what you are asking, at least in the context of `docker-compose up`. There is [an option for specifying env vars with `docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-with-docker-compose-run)):

```
docker-compose run -e DEBUG=1 web python console.py
```

I'm not sure what your use case is, but using [override files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files) has been the best way for me to accomplish having different env vars defined on a per user basis during development or testing/CI.

Comment: My use case is to have sane variable defaults listed in the `env_file` but have the possibility to override them when starting my stack from Jenkins CI where I would set them via build parameters which end up as environment variables. My current work-around is to write these environment variables to a file and replace the default `env_file` with it.
Apparently, it will not get much better than this.

Comment: Yeah. I generally end up with an `env_file` specific to CI environment that I specify my CI provider use. Sounds like a similar approach to what you're doing. I don't know of a better way - hopefully someone else will come along with another suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    env_file:
      - my.env
    environment:
      - FOO=SOMETHING_ELSE
    command: env
```

For whatever reason, `env_file` takes precedence over shell despite the docs saying otherwise. It may be because `env_file` is explicitly stated in the `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: [By the way, according to the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/), "When both `env_file` and `environment` are set for a service, values set by `environment` have precedence."

Comment: @MichaelCurrie right that's why I said, "despite the docs saying otherwise"

Comment: You said "`env_file` takes precedence over shell despite the docs saying otherwise", (which have not checked).  I am saying "`environment` takes precedence over `env_file`, according to the docs", which is different and also I verified it.